# Jmeter webriver result is not coming for remote system

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

Jmeter remote connection is successful and result obtained for localhost but not for remote IP.
As ui load testing i have configure the remote ip in my webdriver code also

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=1099", "--allow-running-insecure-content");
options.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips=192.333.10.333");
```

in code also i am not getting error
Remote connection is successful but result not gained. Any help
jmeter log - INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started:[192.333.10.333, 127.0.0.1]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [RMI ports configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) is not correct, inspect [jmeter-server.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file on slave machine(s) - it should contain more details regarding what went wrong.

Basically you need to

1. Make sure that JMeter master can reach the slaves to send the .jmx test plan to them
2. JMeter slaves can reach master to send results back

Try opening the relevant ports in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)